# Error in singlefold(obs, k) : insufficient records:2, with k=5 / Unused argument (kfolds = 4)

Tags: r, k-fold

The code I used:

```
competition <- ENMevaluate(occ = occ_coord, env = env, bg.coords = bg_coord, method = "randomkfold", RMvalues=seq(0.5, 5, 0.5), fc = c("L", "LQ", "H", "LQH"), algorithm='maxent.jar')
```

Unable to solve this, previously used a different code which sad kfolds is an unused arguement that is why replaced it to the above^

Previous Code:

```
competition <- ENMevaluate(occ = occ_coord, env = env, bg.coords = bg_coord, method = "randomkfold", kfolds=4, RMvalues=seq(0.5,4,0.5), fc = c("L", "LQ", "H", "LQH"), algorithm='maxent.jar')
```

Previous Error:

```
Error in ENMevaluate(occ = occ_coord, env = env, bg.coords = bg_coord,  : unused argument (kfolds = 4)
```

Anything will be helpful right now as I am very short on time (<24 hours).
Thank you!

Comment: Can you please provide the data to reproduce the error? Looks like we would need `occ_coord`, `env`, and `bg_coord`

Comment: https://shandongfx.github.io/NIMBioSENM/
I have used a different species instead. Genus - Rucervus, Species - Rucervus duvaucelii
I have followed the steps from here, if it still is unsolvable and if there is any other website which can provide a step by step tutorial. That would be really helpful.

Comment: Also, the data was cleaned and occurrences with uncertain & duplicated coordinates were removed.

Comment: It's going to be a lot easier for everyone to help if you simply provide the code to reproduce the data. Here is some help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example